# kdb: Is there a way to efficiently merge two sorted tables?

Tags: kdb

Say we have two tables both sorted on the `time` column:

```
t1:`time xasc ([]time:5?100;v:5?1000)
t2:`time xasc ([]time:5?100;v:5?1000)
```

Is there an efficient way to get the same result as `` `time xasc t1,t2 `` , using the fact that the two tables are already sorted? I looked at `aj` but I wasn't able to find the "combine two tables" functionality I need here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no native merge-sort/binary-sort in kdb so the optimal available approach is `asc x,y`. If you go down the path of replicating a merge/binary sort in kdb then you're unlikely to get it faster than the native `asc x,y`. You could alternatively try to write a merge/binary sort in C and import a shared library to use in kdb